# Open modal when user sign in with Devise and rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app with `Devise`. I would like to open a modal dialog when a user sign in the website.

My current solution is that add a url params in `after_sign_in_path_for` method:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  root_url(sign_in: true)
end
```

And then I can check the url params in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <% if params[:sign_in] %>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#login-message-modal').modal()
    });
  <% end %>
</script>
```

But I feel it is tricky. Does anyone know any better solution?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  flash[:modal] = '#login-message-modal'
  root_url
end
```

and

```
<script>
  ....
  <% if flash[:modal] %>
     $('<%= flash[:modal] %>').modal();
  <% end %>
</script>
```

Comment: If you use `flash`, you have to clear it, otherwise it will be kept inside.

Comment: from the docs: "Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the very next action and then cleared out." http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html

if it's persisting there for whatever reason you can always call `#discard`